# JavaCV assertion failed

Tags: java, opencv, k-means, javacv

I am trying to use K-means JavaCV implementation, but I have the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!centers.empty()) in cvKMeans2, file src\matrix.cpp, line 4233
```

My source code is:

```
IplImage src = cvLoadImage(fileName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

int cluster_count = 3;
int attempts = 10;
CvTermCriteria termCriteria = new CvTermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + TermCriteria.MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0);

cvReshape(src, src.asCvMat(), 1, src.height() * src.width());
IplImage samples = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), src.depth(), 1);
cvConvertImage(src, samples, CV_32F);

IplImage labels = cvCreateImage(new CvSize(samples.height()), 1, CV_8U);
IplImage centers = cvCreateImage(new CvSize(cluster_count), 1, CV_32F);

cvKMeans2(samples, cluster_count, labels, termCriteria, 1, new long[attempts], KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, centers, new double[attempts]);
```

I'm beginner on JavaCV and would to know what I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Any specific reason for using `IplImage`?, using `Mat` would do any difference to you ?